# Getting an Warningwhile uploading file to google drive using Java

Tags: java, api, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload file to my Google drive Account using Java. The file is uploaded but i'm getting an warning: **WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName**.

Code is

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;


public class UploadFileGoogleDrive {
      private static String CLIENT_ID = "*****";
      private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "******";
      private static String REDIRECT_URI = "****";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .setAccessType("online")
            .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
        System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

        //Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();

        //Insert a file  
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("My document");
        body.setDescription("A test document");
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
    }

}
```

**The Output is**
May 24, 2014 11:59:14 AM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient 
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
File ID: 1Ze77mqHtKWDU3eVljATlHQ0U

Answer (score 0):

The Google APIs Client Library for Java strongly encourages you to set an application name when constructing your clients, for use when troubleshooting requests against our server logs. You can see an example on how to set the application name in the [Google Drive Java command line sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java?repo=samples#119).